# OTA update for Nexus Prime in India?

Tags: ota-update

I recently bought a Galaxy Nexus Prime from Hong Kong before the release of the Jelly Bean update. Now I'm unable to get the OTA update on my Nexus device.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Go to link provided below. It discribes how to update Galaxy nexus via OTA(over the air).

[Instructions](http://tech2.in.com/how-to/smartphones/how-to-get-jelly-bean-ota-update-on-the-galaxy-nexus/353192)